# Where can we find the GData.framework for iPhone in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

Can anyone suggest me where can I find the GData.framework with steps.

Anyone's help will be much Appreciated.

Thanks to all,
Monish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main GData page is located at http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

Check out the [Introduction to Google Data APIs for Cocoa Developers](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction), as well as some example applications [here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples), and you can view the [introductory slides](https://docs.google.com/present/view?id=dftpzpbs_0g5w3q5cg&pli=1).

Hope this helps!